# What does the following notation mean in geometry angles?

Tags: geometry

What does the following notation mean in geometry angles?

[image]

Comment: Never seen that notation before, but it must refer to the angle subtended by the arc in question.  That is, $\cup AB=\angle AOB$ where $O$ denotes the center of the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time I have seen this notation it meant *arc*, namely $\smile\!\!AB$ would denote arc $AB$. In a similar context I have usually seen $$\stackrel{\Huge\frown}{ABC},$$

using three points to avoid ambiguity (that could also be solved by using *directed* arcs, so that $\stackrel{\LARGE\frown}{AB}$ and $\stackrel{\LARGE\frown}{BA}$ are different). Of course, this notation has the drawback when handwriting, as $\overline{ABC}$ could look very similar. Also, with typed text $\smile\!\!AB$ fits nicely into a line.

In the context of angles and circles, it probably means the length of the arc expressed in terms of the circle radius, which happens to be the measure of angle $\angle AOB$ in radians where $O$ is the center of the circle (as suggested by @lulu). It is no surprise, because radians, the (non-) unit of angle measurement, is expressed in terms of arc length. This guess is compatible with the theorem that passage is describing:

[image: angle crossing circle]

where the red angle is equal to the sum of light blue and light green angles, which are equal to half of the dark blue and dark green angles.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thanks. And does $\angle(AC, BD)$ mean the angle between intersecting $AC$ and $BD$?

Comment: @Dhruv Yes, and that's actually quite common.